Off-centered IMU and how to determine the centripetal force acting on it
I apologize if this is the wrong place to ask questions about IMUs and how they work. My question is: if a 6-DOF IMU is placed off-center from the center of mass of the body being measured, and the body has some angular acceleration, the IMU will experience acceleration due to the centrifugal force acting on it. How can we remove this "error" in the linear accelerometers to find the true linear acceleration of the body? Can we simply use the formula $a=\omega^2r$ (where $\omega$ is the angular velocity and $r$ is the offset distance from the center of mass)
and use the angular velocity to calculate the acceleration, or is there another method, or have I misunderstood the concept entirely?

What does IMU mean?

IMU inertial measurement unit
